# Edit, Add and Delete rows in Silverlight data grid?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I was browsing the internet for a decent example where data is generated with observable collection and with Edit, Add, Delete of rows functionality in the data grid. I am hoping that someone will point me to the nice samples. I am hoping that someone will point me to the nice samples. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[Second hit on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=silverlight+4+datagrid+observablecollection+add+remove): [a bit old but it gives you the basic setup](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/SilverlightCustomerDataGrid09252009180811PM/SilverlightCustomerDataGrid.aspx)